# I have to build an LED lamp with a lithium battery

Tags: led, batteries, lipo, light, lamp

I don't understand much about electronics, I just know that the battery is very dangerous. These are the links of the components that I will use:

- [**BATTERY**](https://www.ebay.it/itm/313551657677?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20160908105057%26meid%3D681be451aaf7451db700eea936553493%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D313551657677%26itm%3D313551657677%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057&_trksid=p2380057.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3Abeac0c11-790b-11ec-9a00-627cceca4c5f%7Cparentrq%3A71b4eb0c17e0ab8c96d3d331fffef78a%7Ciid%3A1) 3.7V 4400mAh
- [**LED**](https://it.rs-online.com/web/p/led/1802607) 11,9V 1050mA
- [**STEP UP BOOST CONVERTER**](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07MY3NZ18/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
  DC 2-24V input and 5V-28V output
- [**USB CHARGE CONTROLLER**](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07Z6KY4XY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1)
- [**POWER BUTTON**](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B0964TH418/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comments and advice of any kind are welcome.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question, not just ask for comments.  What do you want to know?

Comment: Do other components have to be inserted to avoid exploding? I don't know, like a resistance

Comment: If you don't understand much about electronics, then don't buy a lithium battery, buy a 'power brick'. It's USB chargeable, fixed 5 V output, and has all the safety issues that you don't know about addressed (your comment, do other components have to be inserted to avoid exploding?) Yes, lithium batteries can do a lot of damage to you, and you can easily damage them. Don't mess with them lightly. Buy something that's taken care of damage (both ways round) already.

Comment: I already bought it

Comment: Then you should probably return it if you can, and put it in the recycling bin otherwise.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. I'm afraid it's not a free design house and can't be an online personal tutorial. You've been honest about your skill level and being a beginner. It's wonderful to see you start in electronics and we wholeheartedly encourage your learning and enterprising attitude. But I'm afraid you're on the wrong site for what you're looking for. Do some internet searching, you may well find a site more suited to what you need at your stage. Please do persist with your learning and in building this, what you're trying to do is great. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 2):

That DC-DC module won't be able to power your LED. Your LED requires 1050 mA at 11.9V. That means it requires `11.9V * 1.05A = 12.5W` of power.

Your battery **nominal** voltage are 3.7V (it will be up to 4.2V while fully charged and down to 2.7-3.0V while discharged). Even 100% DC-DC converter efficiency (which is never the case, you should refer to a DC-DC IC datasheet), that would be `12.5W / 3V = 4.2A` current. Considering such in-out voltage difference efficiency will be pretty low, somewhere down to 70% (just a guess), that would be actually up to 6A current from the battery. This DC-DC module just can't handle that.

PS: That china-made DC-DC module, while rated at 2A, in fact real current it can handle is around 1-1.5A.